# API.subscribe is undefined in @react-navigation/native useFocusEffect

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am following the code in my project:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/#using-with-class-component

I am getting this - "API.subscribe is undefined in @react-navigation/native useFocusEffect".

Thanks for your help in advance.